# Python Jupyter - hide the figure properties

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

For some reasons, and it doesn't happen all the time, but when plotting a figure in Jupyter using matplotlib, the figure properties gets printed on screen before displaying the figure. For example, I see the following:

```
 adjustable: {'box', 'datalim'}
  agg_filter: a filter function, which takes a (m, n, 3) float array and a dpi value, and returns a (m, n, 3) array
  alpha: float
  anchor: 2-tuple of floats or {'C', 'SW', 'S', 'SE', ...}
  animated: bool
  aspect: {'auto', 'equal'} or num
  autoscale_on: bool
  autoscalex_on: bool
  autoscaley_on: bool
  axes_locator: Callable[[Axes, Renderer], Bbox]
  axisbelow: bool or 'line'
  clip_box: `.Bbox`
  clip_on: bool
  clip_path: [(`~matplotlib.path.Path`, `.Transform`) | `.Patch` | None]
  contains: callable
  facecolor: color
  fc: color
  figure: `.Figure`
  frame_on: bool
  gid: str
  in_layout: bool
  label: object
  navigate: bool
  navigate_mode: unknown
  path_effects: `.AbstractPathEffect`
  picker: None or bool or float or callable
  position: [left, bottom, width, height] or `~matplotlib.transforms.Bbox`
  rasterization_zorder: float or None
  rasterized: bool or None
  sketch_params: (scale: float, length: float, randomness: float)
  snap: bool or None
  subplotspec: unknown
  title: str
  transform: `.Transform`
  url: str
  visible: bool
  xbound: unknown
  xlabel: str
  xlim: (left: float, right: float)
  xmargin: float greater than -0.5
  xscale: {"linear", "log", "symlog", "logit", ...}
  xticklabels: List[str]
  xticks: list
  ybound: unknown
  ylabel: str
  ylim: (bottom: float, top: float)
  ymargin: float greater than -0.5
  yscale: {"linear", "log", "symlog", "logit", ...}
  yticklabels: List[str]
  yticks: list
  zorder: float
```

How can I stop this from happening? Having plt.show() or a semicolon at the of the code that plots my figure does not help.

Below is an example of a plot code:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(13, 4), sharey=True)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace = .4, wspace=.15)
plt.setp(axes)
ax12 = results['news1'].plot(ax=axes[0], grid=False, legend=False, marker='o',
                             fontsize=fs2, markerfacecolor='white', markeredgewidth=1.5, markeredgecolor='blue')
ax12.fill_between(range(-4, 5),
                 results['news1'+' CIm'].values, 
                 results['news1'+' CIp'].values,
                 facecolor='gray', alpha=0.30, interpolate=True)
ax12.set_xlabel('')

ax22 = results['news2'].plot(ax=axes[1], grid=False, legend=False, marker='o',
                             fontsize=fs2, sharey=ax12, markerfacecolor='white',
                             markeredgewidth=1.5, markeredgecolor='blue')
ax22.fill_between(range(-4, 5),
                 results['news2'+' CIm'].values, 
                 results['news2'+' CIp'].values,
                 facecolor='gray', alpha=0.30, interpolate=True)
```

Comment: Please add your code as well?

Comment: add a semicolon after your plot call to prevent this

Comment: I added a sample code that leads to the display of these properties and no, adding a semicolon does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but deleting `plt.setp(axes)` solves this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it is because your last statement returns something, you can add a `;` to the end.

For example:

If this the last statement,

```
ax22.fill_between(range(-4, 5),
                 results['news2'+' CIm'].values, 
                 results['news2'+' CIp'].values,
                 facecolor='gray', alpha=0.30, interpolate=True)
```

Then add a `;`:

```
ax22.fill_between(range(-4, 5),
                 results['news2'+' CIm'].values, 
                 results['news2'+' CIp'].values,
                 facecolor='gray', alpha=0.30, interpolate=True);
```

The problem is that `notebook` will automatically repr the return.